# How to determine if a type is a value type from CLI metadata?

Tags: .net, metadata, value-type

I am using the `IMetaDataImport` API and and I need to determine if the type definitions in my assembly are value or reference types. I have not found any method in the API that explicitely provides this information. However, I can easily enough obtain the base type and check if it is `System.ValueType`.

My question is: is the base class the only way through which CLI metadata encodes the fact that a type is a value type or are there some flags for this somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no flags that identify value types directly. It looks like checking the base type, along with a couple of other things, is the canonical way to do it.

Section II.10.1.3 of the [ECMA CLI spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm) describes the type definition like this:

> The type semantic attributes specify whether an interface, class, or
>   value type shall be defined. The **interface** attribute specifies an
>   interface. If this attribute is not present and the definition extends
>   (directly or indirectly) `System.ValueType`, and the definition is not
>   for `System.Enum`, a value type shall be defined. Otherwise, a class
>   shall be defined.

Comment: Cool, that's clear enough! The "indirectly" part is a bit surprising, though. Does it refer only to enumerations, which inherit from `System.Enum`? I don't see any other legal form of indirect `System.ValueType` inheritance.

Comment: @Trillian: Yes, I think that's right. `System.ValueType` is a class type, `System.Enum` itself is a class type inheriting from `System.ValueType`, but anything else in that inheritance hierarchy will be a value-type.

Answer (score 0):

Is the [`Type.IsValueType` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.type.isvaluetype) what you're looking for?

Comment: Not quite, the fact that this property exists does not indicate that the metadata directly exposes this value. However, you gave me the idea to look at Mono's implementation of this property and it indeeds confirms that value type-ness is determined by checking the inheritance chain.